# print content of page by using htmlentities dont work for google.com

Tags: php, curl

I use this code for print content of web page(source code):

```
<?php
$url='http://cloob.com';
$ch=curl_init();
$timeout=5;

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
// Get URL content
$lines_string=curl_exec($ch);
// close handle to release resources
curl_close($ch);
var_dump( htmlspecialchars($lines_string));
//echo htmlentities($lines_string);
//var_dump( $lines_string);
?>
```

This is working but when I change the URL to `https://google.com`
doesn't work, why?

It worked when I directly use (when I don't use `htmlentities()`) in both situation...
(I use http://phpfiddle.org/)

Comment: Please be more specific than saying "it doesn't work." What results are you seeing? What results do you expect? If there are any error messages, please share them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to do is to read the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

> If the input string contains an invalid code unit sequence within the given encoding an empty string will be returned, unless either the ENT_IGNORE or ENT_SUBSTITUTE flags are set.

So, we might have a problem with PHP parsing the HTML, or encoding isn't right, or HTML isn't right.

When you use a proper encoding for google website, you get the result you want:

```
var_dump( htmlspecialchars($lines_string, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1'));
```

Comment: tnx alot but how i set a function to cover all encodings?

Comment: if you want to ensure an encoded string, you'll need both ENT_SUBSTITUTE and ENT_DISALLOWED. i use `function hhb_tohtml(string $str):string
{
    return htmlentities($str, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML401 | ENT_SUBSTITUTE | ENT_DISALLOWED, 'UTF-8', true);
}`